# Bug in ruby interpreter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, podfile

I am learning React Native and i want to implement google maps in my project. But when i update my podfile and run `pod install`. WebStorm gives me error as

```
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
```

I have already imported GoogleMapAPI in my AppDelgate.m . After importing the API i have update PODDFILE with the following code in my podfile just above `use_native_modules`

```
# React Native Maps dependencies
    rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
    pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path
```

Is there any way to fix this issue???

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'CabMe' do

   # React Native Maps dependencies
    rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
    pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path

  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => false
  )

  target 'CabMeTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  use_flipper!()

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
  end
end
```

I have provided the github repo for my project. Please help me to fix this. I am new to this.

https://github.com/neeteshraj/CabMe